# ControlTreeView is not working in AutoIt Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I want to user the Keywords ControlTreeView to expand the SysTreeView32 in Robotframework,but it does't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the test crash? Does it throw an error? Does it silently do nothing?

Comment: Can you please provide us with an example of the malfunctioning code and the output it provides?